# Retriving the smallest numeric value in array

Tags: php

This script retrieves the last value in an array.

```
$min = array_reduce($values, function($min, $i) {
    if (is_numeric($i) && $i < $mn) {
        return $i;
    }
    return $min;

});
//just an output for myself in case the value is non numeric
if (!is_numeric($min)){
$min="not numeric";
}
```

The problem I have is that the value might not be numeric and I need the smallest numeric one - there always are and numeric values.
How I can create a loop which will keep searching until the smallest numeric value is found?
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: the smallest numeric value will be at the end of array before eventual non numeric ones.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way of doing this would be to filter the array (using `array_filter()`) - only keeping numeric values and then using `min()` to get the smallest...

```
$data = ["a", 1, 1.2, "b", 129000, "r", "0.1"];

echo min(array_filter($data, "is_numeric"));
```

displays

```
0.1
```

This assumes that although 0.1 is a string in the source data, that as it is actually a number then it counts in your definition of being a number.

If you wanted to stick with using a loop, this keeps a `$min` running value, set to null at the start.  Then loops over the data and checks if the new value is a number and if it's the first value or if it's less than the existing minimum, then it sets the new min value.

```
$min = null;
foreach ( $data as $value ) {
    if ( is_numeric($value) && ($min == null || $min > $value ))    {
        $min = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that is better to use array filter but I could not make it work that way (so far). The array holds the values from a csv file column. But the second way, with the loop, works just fine. Many thanks to all for your time!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all sort the array. Then try using a for loop until you find a numeric value. smallest numerical value will be the first numerical value after the array has been sorted. Try using the following code.

Assume the array is `$array`

```
sort($array);
foreach($numbers as $array)
{
    if(is_numeric($array))
    {
        echo $array;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

And I agree with @Nigel Ren's answer using `array_filter` function more quicker than using a loop